# Can a single batch of the CosmosDb change feed contain the same document multiple times?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Assume a particular CosmosDb document gets lots of updates, say 2 per second.

Let's assume the change feed is configured to poll for changes every 10 seconds.

The documentation is clear in stating that some "intermediate" changes may be skipped, but it's not clear if several of these changes can make their way into a single CF batch.

So is it possible that a batch can contain several "versions" of the same document, or is it guaranteed that a particular document only shows up once per batch (in the previous example, the CF will offer roughly every 20-th version of the document)?

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed) aren't very clear:

> **Sort order of items in change feed**
>   Change feed items come in the order of their modification time. This sort order is guaranteed per logical partition key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is guaranteed that you will only get the latest version of a single document in a single lease (physical partition) handle.

["Only the most recent change for a given item is included in the change log"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed)

Comment: [citation needed] ?

Comment: Added the link of the documentation you linked.